# Dependent field in Laravel Nova using Nova Dependency Container

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm quite new to Laravel Nova, and I'm trying to implement dependent fields but there's no easy solution to it. I want to display a checkbox if a certain value is selected in a select dropdown.

After a little searching, I found this: https://github.com/epartment/nova-dependency-container. I'm trying to use this, but something's not working right. I'm using Laravel `v5.7` and Nova `v1.3.2`. Hence, I've installed `v1.1.2` of this package.

I followed the installation guidelines and have written the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

...
use Epartment\NovaDependencyContainer\HasDependencies;
use Epartment\NovaDependencyContainer\NovaDependencyContainer;

...
class Submission extends Resource
{
    use HasDependencies;
    ....
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        $fields[] = Select::make('Route', 'route')->options([
            0 => 'First Name',
            1 => 'First Name / Last Name',
            2 => 'Full Name'
        ])->displayUsingLabels();

        $fields[] = NovaDependencyContainer::make([
            Text::make('Title', 'title')
        ])->dependsOn('route', 2);

        ...

        return $fields;
    }
    ....
}
?>
```

I can see the field Route with the right options and values. However, when I select 'Full Name', the dependent field Title is not displayed.

When I see the JSON response of the fields, this is what I get:

```
...
{
    "component": "select-field",
    "prefixComponent": true,
    "indexName": "Route",
    "name": "Route",
    "attribute": "route",
    "value": null,
    "panel": null,
    "sortable": false,
    "textAlign": "left",
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "First Name",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "label": "First Name / Last Name",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "label": "Full Name",
        "value": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "component": "nova-dependency-container",
    "prefixComponent": true,
    "indexName": "",
    "name": "",
    "attribute": "",
    "value": [],
    "panel": null,
    "sortable": false,
    "textAlign": "left",
    "fields": [
      {
        "component": "text-field",
        "prefixComponent": true,
        "indexName": "Title",
        "name": "Title",
        "attribute": "title",
        "value": null,
        "panel": null,
        "sortable": false,
        "textAlign": "left"
      }
    ],
    "dependencies": [
      {
        "field": "route",
        "value": 2
      }
    ]
  },
...
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Would be great if someone could guide me here. Or if there's another solution that works.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm the maintainer of this package, this feature has not been implemented in version `1.1.2`. Sadly support for Laravel 5.x has been dropped and only supports 6.x/7.x.

Comment: I would also strongly recommend updating to Laravel 7.x and Nova 3.x. A lot of packages will not work with your versions.